# Open local index.html with URL parameters using system()

Tags: r, linux

I want to launch a local website from R (in linux) using system(), but I need to pass a parameter, so I need the "URL" to be something like `/home/myuser/index.html?q=1`.

When I launch it the "?" becomes "%3F":

```
system('google-chrome /home/myuser/index.html?q=1')
```

> file:///home/myuser/index.html%3Fq=1

But this conversion does not happen when launching a website:

```
system('google-chrome https://www.google.com/search?q=hello')
```

> https://www.google.com/search?q=hello

---

So, how can I make `system('google-chrome /home/myuser/index.html?q=1')` go to: `file:///home/myuser/index.html?q=1`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `system('google-chrome file:///home/myuser/index.html?q=1')` work? Is there a reason you don't want to use the `browseURL()` function?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrFlick! Indeed, using the 'file:///home' version solves the issue. browseURL() also works when using 'file:///home'. I got fixated with why the change was happening and got stuck. Thanks again!